# Iterating through a dataframe to create PDF documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pdf, dataframe

I have a worksheet that I have imported as a Pandas dataframe which looks something like this:

FileName       FilePath     Date     Pagestart      PageEnd

file1             path1         date1     5               10

file2             path2         date2     20              100

My goal here is to iterate through the dataframe and create a PDF for each row based on the specified page range. The first row should create a new PDF by pulling pages 5-10 from file1, the second row should build a new PDF by pulling pages 20-100 from file2.

I am having trouble finding a good way to first, iterate through a dataframe and second, create the PDF based on the page range. Is there a way to iterate through a dataframe pretty easily? is there a module that will create PDFs where I can specify a page range (I have used PyPDF2 in the past with .getPage() but I dont think that allows a page range but rather a single value)?

Edit: I think I found a good way to iterate through the dataframe, but am still searching for a way to build the PDF. Here is my iteration:

```
i = 0
for row in df.iterrows():
    iteration = df.iloc[i]
    i +=1
```

Comment: for the iteration you can use `DataFrame.itertuples()`

Comment: you can use `enumerate(iterable)` instead of `i=0` and `I += 1`

Comment: Is enumerate quicker/better? Also, do you have any suggestions on the PDF creation front?

Answer (score 1):

```
import PyPDF2
import os

for row in df.itertuples():
    page_start, page_end = row.PageStart, row.PageEnd
    output_filename = generate_output_name
    filename = os.path.join(row.FilePath, row.FileName)
    with PdfFileMerger() as merger:
        merger.append(filename, pages=(page_start, page_en))
        merger.write(output_filename)
```

Comment: To create a new file for each row, as in the question, you'll need to bring `with PdfFileMerger() as merger:` and `merger.write(output_filename)` into the loop.

Comment: @EFT I changed the answer